# Capturing syscalls of malicious python packages

Tags: python, x86, system-calls, select-syscall

I want to capture syscalls of malicious python packages. Is there any way to do this?
Or can I capture syscalls in wireshark?

For reference: [Typosquatted Python packages](https://thehackernews.com/2021/07/several-malicious-typosquatted-python.html), much like StackOverlow copy/paste.

Comment: if you are running Linux you could use strace, in windows you could use ETW

Comment: Why are you running malicious packages in the first place?

Comment: Wireshark captures network traffic, not system calls.[

Comment: or you could just hook SSDT dispatchers at the kernel level,

Comment: other solutions would be to hook MSR register that direct the syscall to an entry point where you could just put your code there to evaluate which syscall is been called according to Cr3 and stack / registers

Comment: a good solution is just to read the package source code and figure out what is doing, tracing syscalls is hard as there are a lot of calls from modules such as python

Comment: Maybe write a eBPF program to capture the syscalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wireshark does not trace syscalls, it traces the network traffic, two completely different things<sup>note</sup>
2. Why are you even importing and/or installing such packages
3. You can use strace on any */Linux distribution

   3.1. Though strace output is often hard to read, you're better off reading the src
4. Use a virtual machine, just in case you know

Note:  Wireshark can trace USB as well as network traffic.

This is unlikely to solve your problem as `read()` is a function.  If it reads */etc/passwd*, it is different than */etc/python/debian_config*.  You would have to examine the arguments to the syscall.

Comment: Hey, I want to capture the syscalls of a malicious python package which proceed in a software supply chain attack.
Can you tell me how can I strace any package?

Thanks

Comment: @AwaizKhan Read the `strace` command manual, it's very easy. But you won't get very far by tracing system calls (unless the python package is using mostly C code). Python is too high-level. I would investigate some debugging/sandbox solution specific to python (you can monkey-patch almost anything in python).

Comment: @AwaizKhan `strace python3 ....`